# Controls are not displaying in simulator when moving from one viewcontroller to other viewcontroller with navigationcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I placed embedded Navigationcontroller at start of my mainViewController(Login) and added other viewcontroller(Home). In Login View controller i have a button so when i click on the button it should move to HomeViewcontroller, for this i have written Code in button click.It was redirecting to HomeView but having some issues

1)simulator was displaying as black page,if i set background color to white it was displaying as white 
2)labels,textboxes etc any other fields which was drag and dropped to my home view was not displaying.but if i write code to generate the label or textbox i was displaying.

I have Added the constraints to my label(ex: welcome) but also the label wasn't displaying ,not only label any other static fields are not displaying but if i generate through code for any label or textbox it was displaying.

when i remove navigationController there are no issues.

hope i will get an answer to my Question.please help me in this issue. Thanks in Advance

Comment: Can you share your actual code? "for this I have written code" can't be reviewed or debugged.

Answer (score 0):

For Buttonclick i have written the code as below and  in HomeviewController i have drag and dropped the label,textbox,button but none of these was displaying

- (IBAction)btnLogin:(id)sender {

  HomeViewController *destinationController = [[HomeViewController alloc] init];

  [self.navigationController pushViewController:destinationController animated:NO];

}
i was redirecting to homeView but was displaying as blackscreen and i changed the background as white then white screen was appeared but controls was not found